# Objectify - filter() with range and with a 100 records limit does return the same result always?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Objectify filter() with range and with a 100 records limit does return the same result always, is there a way to get 100 random record on a given matching criteria???

**Example:**
Lets say I have an index on score field (in GAE Entity Leaderboard), where I would like to fetch out records where score range is 0 to 10 with a limit of 100 records I do get the same results out all the time (considering there is no change in the data records). I understand this is purely to do with the index where the data could have been stored and ordered in ASC order and any time you query we might end up with the same result?

Is there way with GAE objectify to fetch out the random 100 records matching the same criteria considering we have 1000s of records b/w 0-100 score range???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your specific needs, you may be able to use the `__scatter__` property built into GAE:

https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/ScatterPropertyImplementation

Answer (score 0):

With how the datastore indexes, no.

The datastore reads through his index, the index is pre-sorted, so it will always return the SAME value.

The only way to get such a "randomizer" effect would be to grab your 1000s of records and randomly select 100 of them, or create an auto-incrementing number for your 1000s of records you want to have, and then grab a random interval of a 100.

EDIT: by the OP's suggestion, another solution would be to pre-fetch a simple count, then randomly generate an offset number to grab random data.  (added to the answer for sake of having all solutions at one place)

Comment: I just got an idea and I believe that can be a solution. However could be a performance hit not sure though. 

**Solution:** we can first fetch out the count of records in the given range, and then calculate a random offset and set it to fetch the records???

Comment: Yes definitely, that would work. It's pretty much the same logic as my auto-incrementing ID, but it would definitely work

Comment: One thing with your method though @VSivaReddy, is that it will be expensive. A count query actually counts as X queries (where X is the result), so it might make your price jump a bit. This is why I suggested adding an auto-incrementing number attribute. That will keep the queries lower.  Will make you write more indexes though.